# Add transition effects to my image slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

i´m working in an image slider, and i´m trying to do one from sratch so that I can learn in the process.
What I was able to do is very simple, and I want to add a transition effect, such as fade out, or something like that. If someone knows how to add it to my code it would help me a lot. 
Here is what I did so far:

```js
var currentIndex = 0,
  items = $('.container div'),
  itemAmt = items.length;

function cycleItems() {
  var item = $('.container div').eq(currentIndex);
  items.hide();
  item.css('display','inline-block');
}

var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
  currentIndex += 1;
  if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  cycleItems();
}, 3000);

$('.next').click(function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide);
  currentIndex += 1;
  if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  cycleItems();
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide);
  currentIndex -= 1;
  if (currentIndex < 0) {
    currentIndex = itemAmt - 1;
  }
  cycleItems();
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.container div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  display: none;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
}

.next {
  right: 5px;
}

.prev {
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="demo">
  <button class="next">Next</button>
  <button class="prev">Previous</button>
  <div class="container">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/people"/>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/any"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/nature"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/architecture"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/animals"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/people"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/tech"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) from jQuery.

```
item.fadeIn();
```

**Run this code snippet:**

```js
var currentIndex = 0,
  items = $('.container div'),
  itemAmt = items.length;

function cycleItems() {
  var item = $('.container div').eq(currentIndex);
  items.hide();
  item.fadeIn();//css('display','inline-block');
}

var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
  currentIndex += 1;
  if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  cycleItems();
}, 3000);

$('.next').click(function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide);
  currentIndex += 1;
  if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  cycleItems();
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide);
  currentIndex -= 1;
  if (currentIndex < 0) {
    currentIndex = itemAmt - 1;
  }
  cycleItems();
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.container div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  display: none;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
}

.next {
  right: 5px;
}

.prev {
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="demo">
  <button class="next">Next</button>
  <button class="prev">Previous</button>
  <div class="container">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/people"/>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/any"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/nature"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/architecture"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/animals"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/people"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/tech"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```